# Do not mutate Vuex Store outside of Mutation Handlers

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

Why is this NOT WORKING AND NOT OK:

```
  async login ({ dispatch, state }, user) {
    const token = await this.$fireAuth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)

    const userInfo = user

    Cookies.set('access_token', token) // saving token in cookie for server rendering
    await dispatch('setUSER', userInfo)
    await dispatch('saveUID', userInfo.uid)
  },
```

but this is OK AND WORKING:

```
  async login ({ dispatch, state }, user) {
    const token = await this.$fireAuth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)

    const userInfo = {
      displayName: "Nicl",
      email: user.email,
      avatar: user.photoURL,
      uid: user.uid,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified
    }


    Cookies.set('access_token', token) // saving token in cookie for server rendering
    await dispatch('setUSER', userInfo)
    await dispatch('saveUID', userInfo.uid)
  },
```

I dont get it why do I get the error it seems random to me?

Comment: Are you sure that `user` has `displayName` field? Because you just put it manually in the second code.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Yes the problem is my whole application is buggy on the first login and only works after page refresh because displayName is always said to be undefined, thats why i tried to set it here manually but that also didnt fix it, but thats a different problem, usually firebase displayName should be null if not set

Comment: There is no line in your code example, that may be responsible for mutating state. Add `setUser` and `saveUID` actions code for complete example. If there is a privacy issue, try to delete them from your `login` action and see if error persists/